# how to use openCV image to compile a cpp which uses opencv

Tags: c++, docker, opencv

If I had understood correctly:

We can use a docker image of something instead of installing it.

I don't want to install openCV.

So I install the image :

```
docker pull spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
```

I have a really simple cpp file which use openCV.

What should i do now to compile my file with this image.

Answer (score 0):

1. in the terminal run

   docker run -it --name myopencv spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
2. open new terminal and copy your cpp file to the running container. for example i copy the file 1.cpp to tmp folder to myopencv container.

   docker cp .\1.cpp myopencv:/tmp
3. return to the running container and run g++ <filename.cpp>

** the image you pulled already has all build-essential installed